# ASP.NET Multi-Proc Publish Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have an asp.net 4.0 project which uses visual studio publishing. Is there a way I can speed it up possibly by forcing multi-proc build?

It is using aspnet_compiler and aspnet_merge. I couldn't see any cmd line switches for multi-thread/ multi-proc support.

I already have an SSD and it didn't seem to speed up the compile time much when it was added.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx

I might be wrong, but if you build before you publish and do not make changes you should not have to re-build during publish. Therefore, using information from the above article you should be able to build it much faster.

Comment: I think the bottle neck is the aspnet_compiler and aspnet_merge. If I try to build it with msbuild it will trigger those processes. They are multi-threaded but seem to use no more than 15-20% of my cpu.